# How to create interdependent gems with bundler, and use repositories as the source?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

How is it possible to create interdependent gems, and still use Bundler?

Right now, if the `Gemfile` for `library-a` reads like this:

```
gem 'library-b'
gem 'library-c'
```

And the `Gemfile` for `library-b` reads like this:

```
gem 'library-a'
gem 'library-c'
```

And the `Gemfile` for `library-c` reads:

```
gem 'library-a', github: 'library-root/library-a', branch: 'master'
gem 'library-b', github: 'library-root/library-b', branch: 'master'
```

When you try to run `bundle update` and/or `bundle install` for `library-c`, this is the output:

```
Your Gemfile requires gems that depend depend on each other,
creating an infinite loop. Please remove either gem 'library-a'
or gem 'library-b' and try again.
```

A variation of the same message will happen for `library-a` or `library-b`.

But if you use the following for `library-c`, and use the same style for `library-b` and `library-a`, this will work:

```
gem.add_dependency 'library-a'
gem.add_dependency 'library-b'
```

*However* now, you will need to cut and push gems to RubyGems to test each revision, especially when using Travis CI. Whereas if you'd used `Gemfile` definitions, even if you also used `gemspec` definitions, the code being run or tested would have been pulled from a git repository, and could be updated up-to-the-minute without cutting and pushing gems.

I've posted two issues about this.

- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3594
- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3597

I need to have interdependent gems, *and* use git repositories as the source of the gem code.

---

For those who say *just don't do it* ... "it's `Circular Dependency`", etc. I understand, but let's think about this. Is a gem really that complicated? It's just files with a certain structure. True, it has version information, and "dependencies" associated -- but those dependencies just need to be present. If a gem of the appropriate version exists already, it ought to just break out of a "circular dependency" and say, "hey, the gem's already here, let's just move forward" then.

---

`Bundler` is a *package management system*; the above is not `Circular Dependency` of *objects* it is `Interdependency` of *files* ... if it were Objects inheriting from each other, definitely... I surrender. But this is a point where one package assumes another exists in the filesystem.

You could change the word `depends` to `expects the presence of` not `requires specifically sequential instantiation of`.

Again `gemspec` works. If it were `Circular Dependency` that would be impossible. But `gemspec` is clearer on its purpose as part of a package management system. It lets files be files.

`gemspec` behavior? Both gems need each other? Cool! Download both gems. Easy, done.
`Gemfile` behavior? Both gems need each other? Wait, what? Implode.

I want `gemspec` "dependency" behavior, with `Gemfile` source specificity power. Otherwise I'd just keep using `gemspec` only.

Comment: You have three gems that are fully interdependent. Why have they been extracted into separate gems at all? Is there any scenario in which one of these gems can be used independently of the others?

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is warning you that your gems have a circular dependancy. Namely library-a depends on library-b and the other way around. This is a situation that should be avoided.

If 2 libraries can't exist without each other it's best to just make them one.

Comment: I just separated them, they were one before. The issue only happens if the "circular" gems are listed as `runtime` dependencies, and not `development` so I know the issue is not truly a show stopper.