# Is there a way to have bundler automatically require gems without specifying them in the gemfile?

Tags: bundler

I am trying to get a custom rspec formatter to work across multiple projects that use bundler.  Since I have installed the rspec formatter as a global gem, I was hoping that I would not need to add the gem to every project's gemfile.

Is there a way to have bundler automatically do:

```
group :test { gem 'my-globally-installed-rspec-formatter' }
```

So that any project in a test environment will have that dependency loaded automatically but not require it in its actual Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I realized that there is an rspec flag --require which will autoload a dependency... So I was able to install the gem in my local rvm gemset, and then make a ~/.rspec file with:

```
--color
--tty
--require '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/fancy-formatter-0.11/lib/fancy_formatter.rb'
--format FancyFormatter
```

and it automatically works in all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can put gems in `.gemspec` but that's basically the same issue as having it in `Gemfile`

How I solved the issue is to include two lines of middleware in both the `.gemspec` and the `Gemfile`, then to move all the gem dependencies out of both `Gemfile` and `.gemspec`

**This is handled by using a submodule.** That is scary to a lot of people.

For some people this can be like flying a spaceship five city blocks, but for people managing 5+ gems as a group, all with the same dependencies, it helps. Add to that things like universal RuboCop standards, and it becomes valuable to use a shared submodule.

Once you implement a submodule, your `Gemfile` could look like this, from the current version of `Celluloid` where we have a `celluloid/culture` submodule being implemented:

```
require File.expand_path("../culture/sync", __FILE__)
Celluloid::Sync::Gemfile[self]
```

That references this method...

```
module Celluloid
  module Sync
    module Gemfile
      class << self
        def [](dsl)
          dsl.source("https://rubygems.org")
          dsl.gemspec
          Gems.gemfile(dsl)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which in turn runs this method, in `Celluloid::Gems` ...

```
def gemfile(dsl)
  loader do |name, spec|
    params = [name, spec["version"] || ">= 0"]
    req = spec["gemfile"] || {}
    params << req.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), o| o[k.to_sym] = v }
    current = dsl.dependencies.find { |d| d.name == name }
    dsl.dependencies.delete(current) if current
    dsl.gem(*params)
  end
end

private

def loader
  @dependencies.each do |name, spec|
    next if name == gem_name
    spec ||= {}
    yield name, spec
  end
end
```

Which loops through the `yaml` file preloaded into `@dependencies`...

```
bundler:
nenv:
dotenv:

benchmark_suite:
  dependency: development

rubocop:
  dependency: development

pry:
  dependency: development

rake:
  dependency: development

rspec:
  dependency: development

coveralls:
  gemfile:
    require: false

celluloid:
  dependency: core
  version: ">= 0.17.0.pre7"
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/celluloid
    branch: 0.17.0-prerelease
    submodules: true

celluloid-essentials:
  dependency: module
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/celluloid-essentials
    branch: master
    submodules: true

celluloid-supervision:
  dependency: module
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/celluloid-supervision
    branch: master
    submodules: true

celluloid-pool:
  dependency: module
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/celluloid-pool
    branch: master
    submodules: true

celluloid-fsm:
  dependency: module
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/celluloid-fsm
    branch: master
    submodules: true

celluloid-extras:
  dependency: module
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/celluloid-extras
    branch: master
    submodules: true

timers:
  version: "~> 4.0.0"
  gemfile:
    github: celluloid/timers

rspec-logsplit:
  version: ">= 0.1.2"
  gemfile:
    github: "abstractive/rspec-logsplit"
    branch: "master"
    require: false
```

There is a similar technique also applied for `.gemspec`, which looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path("../culture/sync", __FILE__)

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  #de Unique statements which are not shareable.    
  Celluloid::Sync::Gemspec[gem]
end
```

You should check out the [celluloid/culture](http://github.com/celluloid/culture) repository yourself to see the entire solution, which includes a mechanism to automatically update the submodule in the various gems, when you run `bundle update` for example.

For us, the problem explained and solved above was so annoying it spawned this approach which could end up being its own 'product', especially since it solves [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893470/how-to-create-interdependent-gems-with-bundler-and-use-repositories-as-the-sour) in `Bundler` also, but this entire arrangement is very rarely truly needed. I imagine this approach is controversial. If you have interest in this strategy, I could release my solution in a reusable way.